# How to fix WorldWind26 SocketTimeoutExceptions?

Tags: java, socket-timeout-exception, worldwind

I currently upgraded to WorldWind 2.1.0 to stop getting the Retrieval failed errors since they made the switch to using Https. After making the switch globe tiling started working again, but I still get some retrieval failed errors. Does anyone know why this may be happening. I am also getting two SocketTimeoutExceptions and I do not know why. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below are my errors. The globe continues to work fine and tile just these errors pop up. If there is no fix in the case of WorldWind accessing servers that don't exist anymore is there a way to catch these exceptions caused by WorldWind? Thanks.

```
SEVERE: Retrieval failed for https://worldwind26.arc.nasa.gov/ele...&VERSION=1.3.0
Feb 08, 2017 2:22:43 PM gov.nasa.worldwind.util.SessionCacheRetr ievalPostProcessor run
SEVERE: Retrieval failed for https://worldwind26.arc.nasa.gov/ele...&VERSION=1.3.0
Feb 08, 2017 2:22:43 PM gov.nasa.worldwind.util.SessionCacheUtil s retrieveSessionData
SEVERE: Exception while retrieving resources for https://worldwind26.arc.nasa.gov/ele...&VERSION=1.3.0
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitFo rConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socket Connect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85 )
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConne ct(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect ToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:2 06)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSo cketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSo cketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(S SLSocketImpl.java:668)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkC lient.java:175)
at sun.net.http://www.http.HttpClient.openServe...lient.java:432)
at sun.net.http://www.http.HttpClient.openServe...lient.java:527)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.< init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
at sun.net.http://www.protocol.https.HttpsClien...lient.java:367)
at sun.net.http://www.protocol.https.AbstractDe...ction.java:191)
at sun.net.http://www.protocol.http.HttpURLConn...tion.java:1138)
at sun.net.http://www.protocol.http.HttpURLConn...tion.java:1032)
at sun.net.http://www.protocol.https.AbstractDe...ction.java:177)
at sun.net.http://www.protocol.http.HttpURLConn...tion.java:1546)
at sun.net.http://www.protocol.http.HttpURLConn...tion.java:1474)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCo de(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
at sun.net.http://www.protocol.https.HttpsURLCo...nImpl.java:338)
at gov.nasa.worldwind.retrieve.HTTPRetrieve r.doRead(HTTPRetriever.java:48)
at gov.nasa.worldwind.retrieve.URLRetriever .read(URLRetriever.java:368)
at gov.nasa.worldwind.retrieve.URLRetriever .call(URLRetriever.java:244)
at gov.nasa.worldwind.retrieve.URLRetriever .call(URLRetriever.java:27)
at gov.nasa.worldwind.util.SessionCacheUtil s.retrieveSessionData(SessionCacheUtils. java:80)
at gov.nasa.worldwind.util.SessionCacheUtil s.getOrRetrieveSessionCapabilities(Sessi onCacheUtils.java:170)
at gov.nasa.worldwind.terrain.BasicElevatio nModel.retrieveResources(BasicElevationM odel.java:2028)
at gov.nasa.worldwind.terrain.BasicElevatio nModel$3.run(BasicElevationModel.java:21 18)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Feb 08, 2017 2:22:43 PM gov.nasa.worldwind.util.SessionCacheUtil s retrieveSessionData
SEVERE: Exception while retrieving resources for https://worldwind26.arc.nasa.gov/ele...&VERSION=1.3.0
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitFo rConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socket Connect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85 )
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConne ct(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect ToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:2 06)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSo cketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSo cketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(S SLSocketImpl.java:668)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkC lient.java:175)
at sun.net.http://www.http.HttpClient.openServe...lient.java:432)
at sun.net.http://www.http.HttpClient.openServe...lient.java:527)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.< init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
at sun.net.http://www.protocol.https.HttpsClien...lient.java:367)
at sun.net.http://www.protocol.https.AbstractDe...ction.java:191)
at sun.net.http://www.protocol.http.HttpURLConn...tion.java:1138)
at sun.net.http://www.protocol.http.HttpURLConn...tion.java:1032)
at sun.net.http://www.protocol.https.AbstractDe...ction.java:177)
at sun.net.http://www.protocol.http.HttpURLConn...tion.java:1546)
at sun.net.http://www.protocol.http.HttpURLConn...tion.java:1474)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCo de(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
at sun.net.http://www.protocol.https.HttpsURLCo...nImpl.java:338)
at gov.nasa.worldwind.retrieve.HTTPRetrieve r.doRead(HTTPRetriever.java:48)
at gov.nasa.worldwind.retrieve.URLRetriever .read(URLRetriever.java:368)
at gov.nasa.worldwind.retrieve.URLRetriever .call(URLRetriever.java:244)
at gov.nasa.worldwind.retrieve.URLRetriever .call(URLRetriever.java:27)
at gov.nasa.worldwind.util.SessionCacheUtil s.retrieveSessionData(SessionCacheUtils. java:80)
at gov.nasa.worldwind.util.SessionCacheUtil s.getOrRetrieveSessionCapabilities(Sessi onCacheUtils.java:170)
at gov.nasa.worldwind.terrain.BasicElevatio nModel.retrieveResources(BasicElevationM odel.java:2028)
at gov.nasa.worldwind.terrain.BasicElevatio nModel$3.run(BasicElevationModel.java:21 18)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Have you tried running the query in your browser? The  "https://worldwind26.arc.nasa.gov/ele...&VERSION=1.3.0" string

Comment: Yeah the url is not found. I assume that whatever needs to call it fails to retrieve the data since url is not working. I am not sure how to stop this call or point it to proper url.

Comment: I have same problem. see this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44598508/5538979